# Ripple Effect in Android Recycler View is not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add a ripple effect for the entire row (like we see in listview) in my Recycler View when the row is clicked.

I have tried

```
   android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="true"
```

But still, I couldn't get the desired behavior. Even I have tried

```
   android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

But still no improvement

My **listrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/heading"
           android:text="Title"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:paddingTop="5dp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/subHeading"
           android:id="@+id/size"
           android:text="Sub Title"
           android:paddingTop="3dp"
           android:paddingLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And My layout with Recycler View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_spacing_half"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_spacing_half"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:context=".ListFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/listrow" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my adapter source code

```
    private class listAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

        private final int mItemCount;
        final ArrayList<String> mTitles;
        final ArrayList<String> msTitles;
        ArrayList<RadioButton> radioButtons=new ArrayList<>();

        listAdapter(int itemCount, ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> sTitles) {
            mItemCount = itemCount;
            mtitles=titles;
            msTitles=sTitles;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.sTitle.setTag(position);
            holder.radioButton.setTag(position);
            holder.title.setTag(position);
            holder.title.setText(mTitles.get(position));
            holder.sTitle.setText(msTitles.get(position));
            View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ItemCheckChanged(v);
                }
            };
            holder.radioButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
            holder.sTitle.setOnClickListener(listener);
            holder.title.setOnClickListener(listener);
            if(radioButtons.size()==0){
                holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
                selectedItem=0;
            }
            radioButtons.add(holder.radioButton);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItemCount;
        }

        void ItemCheckChanged(View v){
            selectedItem=(int)v.getTag();
            for(RadioButton radioButton:radioButtons){
                radioButton.setChecked(false);
            }
            radioButtons.get(selectedItem).setChecked(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public int getSelectedIndex(){
            return selectedItem;
        }

    }
```

NOTE: I'm using these all things in BottomSheetDialog may it be reason?

Comment: Try `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @sdex No, it's also not working.

Comment: Instead of `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` try using `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: Please share your adapter source code, where you set click listener.

Comment: You can set your custom ripple effect for pre API 21 devices and post API 21 devices. Here is the link https://suragch.medium.com/adding-a-ripple-effect-to-an-android-recyclerview-item-61249eb382b0

Comment: @sdex I have posted my source code.

Comment: @Deeksha I have tried your solution but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set background to views that have set a click listener. 
If you want to set the listener to the whole row you need to call only: 
`holder.itemView.setOnclickListener()` and remove rest of them.

Comment: Yep, I got it but it was too fast is there any way to slow down animation?

Comment: Nope, it's a system-wide setting that can be changed in developer settings only. You can use 3rd party libraries to have more control over animation.